# how we insert multiple data into a table one column in sql

Tags: codeigniter

```
$query= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO _errorlog SET errors = ".$this->db->escape($post['season']).$this->db->escape($post['venue']).$this->db->escape($post['week'])($post['home_team']).$this->db->escape($post['away_team']));
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '('  giving this type of error in model

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this,

```
$query= $this->db->query("INSERT INTO _errorlog SET errors = ".$this->db->escape($post['season']).$this->db->escape($post['venue']).$this->db->escape($post['week']).$this->db->escape($post['home_team']).$this->db->escape($post['away_team']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database query was wrong.

Check ($post['home_team']) at your db query, looks like you have forget add .$this->dbc->escape().

```
 $q = INSERT INTO _errorlog SET errors = ".$this->db->escape($post['season']).$this->db->escape($post['venue']).$this->db->escape($post['week'])($post['home_team']).$this->db->escape($post['away_team'])
```

So your query should be this.

```
  $q = 'INSERT INTO _errorlog SET errors = "'.$this->db->escape($post['season']).$this->db->escape($post['venue']).$this->db->escape($post['week']).$this->db->escape($post['home_team']).$this->db->escape($post['away_team']).'"';
```